# mac safari show full console.log output

Tags: javascript, debugging, safari, console.log

[image: safari console output]

how to setting safari develop tool ?

[image: safari console output]

Comment: Have you tried clicking on the output?

Comment: yes, this is clicked.

Comment: Can u please share the full error screen shot . i.e your trying to print an array correct?

Answer (score 0):

Safari Does not Support Printing the data fully in array like chrome browser, if u want to print data, print by individual array item and check